# Reduced QR decomposition with eigen

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

I am trying to solve the classical least squares problem `argmin (Ax - b)^2` using Eigen. I know that the system is overdetermined (i.e., `m >= n` where A is `m x n`) and that A has full rank (`n`). I have opted to use the sparse QR part of Eigen, since A is sparse itself. I got as far as this:

```
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <Eigen/SparseQR>

void solve_least_squares(const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>& matrix,
                         const Eigen::VectorXd& rhs)
{
  int m = matrix.rows();
  int n = matrix.cols();

  assert(m >= n);
  assert(matrix.isCompressed());

  Eigen::SparseQR<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, Eigen::COLAMDOrdering<int>> decomposition(matrix);

  Eigen::VectorXd t = (decomposition.matrixQ().transpose() * rhs).topRows(n);

  std::cout << t << std::endl;

  Eigen::VectorXd s = decomposition.matrixR().topRows(n).triangularView<Eigen::Upper>().solve(t);

  return decomposition.colsPermutation().inverse()*s;
}
```

But I am wondering if this is the most efficient implementation: Firstly, Eigen seems to determine the *full* QR decomposition rather than a reduced one (`Q` is `m x m` rather than `m x n`). This seems wasteful, since I only need the top `n` rows.

In the dense case, there is any example in the [HouseholderQR](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1HouseholderQR.html) class:

```
MatrixXf A(MatrixXf::Random(5,3)), thinQ(MatrixXf::Identity(5,3)), Q;
A.setRandom();
HouseholderQR<MatrixXf> qr(A);
Q = qr.householderQ();
thinQ = qr.householderQ() * thinQ; // <- here
std::cout << "The complete unitary matrix Q is:\n" << Q << "\n\n";
std::cout << "The thin matrix Q is:\n" << thinQ << "\n\n";
```

Here, a matrix multiplication is use to obtain the reduced `Q`, which seems even more inefficient than slicing the full matrix.

Since the (dense) SVD decomposition of Eigen provides an option to compute a thin SVD, is there a similar option for QR decompositions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the decomposition the `Q` factor is stored as a sequence of Householder vectors, and the `matrixQ()` method essentially returns a reference to that matrix (which overloads multiplication in a way "as if" multiplying by the actual matrix). When stored as Householder matrix, it makes no difference if `Q` represents the full or thin part of `Q` (actually, multiplying a vector by the full matrix can be done efficiently in-place).

If you want to solve your linear system, you should just write

```
Eigen::VectorXd s = decomposition.solve(rhs);
```

---

Btw: If you are fine with losing some precision (and your matrix is sufficiently well conditioned), you are (in most cases) faster by solving the normal equation (Matlab notation):

```
x = (A'*A) \ (A'*b)
```

and using a sparse Cholesky decomposition (e.g., `Eigen::SimplicialLLT` or `Eigen::SimplicialLDLT`). But benchmark that with your actual data, and check if the accuracy is sufficient for your use-case (maybe after a refinement step, which re-uses the Cholesky decomposition).

Comment: Well, I am skeptical with respect to a Cholesky decomposition, but I will try it nonetheless. Regarding the multiplication: I need to compute `Q^T*b`, i.e., `b^T*Q`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: For the Cholesky path, there is no `Q` and otherwise you should just call the `solve` method.

Comment: But I think the `solve()` would, well, solve `A*x=b`, which is impossible, since the system is infeasible...

Comment: What is your assumption about `solve()` based on? Please check this page: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__LeastSquares.html